# Remove each individual item from an array one by one after they are used?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have a map where after I added a component from an array I want that specific component to be deleted from that array.  I tried methods of filtering then removing but it only removes one item from the array. I need each item of the array deleted after its been used. This is what it looks like:

```
   private var labelViews: [MapLabelView] = []


    private func removeAllLabels() {
        guard let mapController = viewModel.mapController,
            let currentMap = mapController.currentMap else {
                return
        }
    >         labelViews.forEach { view in
    >             DispatchQueue.main.async {
    >                 mapController.removeComponent(view, on: currentMap)
    >                 self.labelViews.removeAll(where: {$0 == view})                
                  if let index = self.campusLabelViews.firstIndex(of: view) 
                  {self.campusLabelViews.remove(at: index)}//This is what I tried doing, but its only removing the first view and not ones after that.
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example what your array looks like before and after the operation?

Comment: @koen its an array of custom objects, I'm checking the count after the remove, but its only showing one less object when it should be empty

Comment: Can you write it out? For instance before: `["one", "two", "three"]`, after: `["two", three"]`. Or something like that?

Comment: @koen its a bit tough because they are views, but the function I'm using is posted above

Comment: you need to get all indexes .. instead of just first right ?

Comment: @jawadAli yes, but only after the object has been removed from map

Comment: what does campusLabelViews have?

Comment: @jawadAli it has a var destinationId: Int and private var textLabel: UILabel!

Answer (score 1):

here is the extension through which you can get all indexes of certain view present in array

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func allIndexes(of element: Element) -> [Int] {
        return self.enumerated().filter({ element == $0.element }).map({ $0.offset })
    }
}
```

so your code will become

```
let indexs = self.campusLabelViews. allIndexes(of: view) // it return all indexes of that particular view 
for index in indexs {
    self.campusLabelViews.remove(at: index)
  }
```